# Using Yiic for plugin migration

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I've been trying to follow the docs for creating a plugin migration (https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/migrations) but any attempts to run yiic seem to die with:

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.
```

My Google-fu has not come up with any relevant answers. This is with Craft setup in a Vagrant box, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've run into this as well when following [this tutorial](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/06/16/craft-console-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using 'localhost' for the 'server' in `craft/config/db.php`, try '127.0.0.1' and visa-versa.

For some reason, some environments are picky about that when connecting to MySQL from the CLI.

Comment: That was it (sort of). I had multiple environments in the config file, but yiic needed something in the default (*) array.

Comment: Ahh, yeah.  There is no domain to match, so it needs something for the default.  Nice catch.

Comment: I still have this issue, any other ideas to try?

Comment: @LukeHolder I'm out of ideas. Those are usually the 2 reasons I've seen it happen.

Comment: had to drop using yiic... manual migration creation for me!

Comment: I tried setting the unixSocket though, didn't seem to work ([link to code](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php#L53-L58))

Comment: It seems you need every config line of your local environment in the default `'*' => array(`. So don't forget `user`, `password` and `database`...

Comment: unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock did the trick for me. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852050/yii-console-command-cant-connect-to-database?rq=1